# What development options are there for proprietary BTLE profiles?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on a bluetooth le project that will bind to android and iOS. I looked at the [TI CC2540 dev kit](http://www.ti.com/tool/CC2540DK), but I am not sure what I need to do to prototype with it. Are there alternatives to the IAR compiler? If not, how easy/friendly is it to push firmware/profiles? Can I change the CC2540 module roles (have one as a peripheral and one as a broadcaster)?

Essentially, can I use the CC2540 dev kit (with IAR if need be) and program write a really simple application that with use the GATT protocol and stack?

Comment: I've read that TI has only provided a binary bluetooth stack that only works with the IAR compiler.  So, you can only use something else if you don't want to use bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

The kit that you have quoted is simply a demo that helps you to evaluate the TI solution. The two devices are programmed with two different firmwares: the first one works as a Peripheral while the other one works as a Central.

TI provides you also a large number of demos with related source code, hence using IAR you can develop your application.